# Is it possible to show the Stack Exchange flair on LinkedIn?

Tags: discussion, flair, linkedin

I have found the HTML to show the flair, and I was wondering if it was possible to place this in a LinkedIn profile.

Where would be the best place to put it?

Comment: Asking for the best place to put it is a Linkedin question, not an SO one.

Comment: (I'll put my answer in a comment instead as this was closed before I could post it.) Interesting idea. As far as I can tell it's not possible though, as you can't include any arbitrary HTML in a LinkedIn profile. So the closest would probably be to simply include a link to your SO profile.

Comment: I am having similar question which is closed due to this question. [How can I show my flair on Facebook, or Google+](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124991/how-can-i-show-my-flair-on-facebook-or-google)

Comment: Posted on 2012-09-04 on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30699/stack-exchange-user-flair-on-linkedin

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji I did it by adding SO as a Certification with a website link to my profile.  But, there is no SO image/icon and it doesn't really stand out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems like it wouldn't be too hard to write a LinkedIn application for this.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the only way to do it. Cannot include arbitary HTML or hotlink to an image.

Comment: Turns out there was an existing meta question about this very topic: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/is-there-any-value-in-creating-an-app-that-will-link-so-and-sf-rep-scores-with-li

Comment: I thought about this a bit more, and while it *technically* wouldn't be hard at all, there would be other major obstacles: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/is-there-any-value-in-creating-an-app-that-will-link-so-and-sf-rep-scores-with-li/23648#23648

Comment: [LinkedIn Apps are now officially dead](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34324), and are replaced by a "Media Linking Feature", which works so-so.

Answer (score 54):

You could place your flair within a Google Presentation embedded in your LinkedIn profile. Check my profile:

http://www.linkedin.com/in/leniel

Here's a blog post I wrote about it:

http://www.leniel.net/2011/01/showcase-stackoverflow-flair-linkedin.html

**[ Update ]**

LinkedIn has revamped their profile editing features and now it's possible to add a link that points directly to your StackOverflow flair. Just click the "Add a link to a video, image, document, presentation." Then enter your flair URL. Mine is this one (replace the last part with your StackOverflow user id):

[`https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/114029.png`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/114029.png)

The good part is that the flair image reflects your current rep (is updatable) and so is a great win over the older Google Presentation method where the image wouldn't be updated.

Comment: I don't have an "add media" option. It looks like it might still be under limited release: http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34324

Comment: Is it possible to make this a hyperlink to our page on StackOverflow, Server Fault or Stack Exchange? I cannot find a way to make it work.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: Yes, it's possible. My LinkedIn profile has a flair that points directly to my StackOverflow profile.

Comment: Thanks @LenielMacaferi . Your article refers to the Google Presentation method, and I wasn't sure if that was still relevant. Does the image update dynamically when our reputation increases? Unfortunately I cannot see your LinkedIn profile as it is not public.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski In fact, the StackOverflow badge is only visible to your connections. http://www.linkedin.com/in/leniel is only visible to people outside of LinkedIn and so it won't show the StackOverflow badge. Just sent you an invitation to connect on LinkedIn so that you can see the StackOverflow badge on my profile there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I included the image in [my profile](http://www.linkedin.com/in/stefanlasiewski) as well, and I'm trying a couple different formats. The Google Presentation method didn't work for me (Couldn't get it to work using Google Docs either), but I'll try a few tweaks.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: the image updates but it may take sometime (days)... I confirm that I can see your flairs on your LinkedIn profile. Really nice. Congrats! :)

Comment: To display your flare on a specific site, just add the URL of that site. For example, my drupal.stackexchange.com flare is http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/flair/7100.png

Comment: Thing is, if I'm just going to add a link, why not link directly to my *profile* on SO or another SE site?

Comment: this works, but looks wired pic for specific exchange site , if you use flair of multiple Stack Exchange site, it looks fine over linkden, Dont know now if stack specific site flair needs to improve or linkdin

Answer (score 19):

In new LinkedIn profile layout you can add "media" to each block. I've added url to my flair in my summary block and account url to it's description.
Here You can see how it looks like:

http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=74055129

- minus: it's visible only on your "non-public" profile
- plus: it's
  using an actual flair url, so it's dynamically changing with your
  rep.

**Edit:**

Turns out that miniature created by SO isn't refreshed. So to see Your actual score You have to click on the content and view it as a "popup window". I would be happy with some better way to do this.

**Edit 2:**

It is refreshed, but only periodically.

**Edit 3:**

Screen:

[image: SO badge on LinkedIn]

Comment: I would like to see, but it is just as you said. I can't view your profile at all, because we know no one in common. It doesn't even show me a "public" profile. I will try that on my profile on LinkedIn, as your answer seems like the best idea so far!

Comment: It would be more convincing if you can post a screenshot to let others see what it looks like.

Comment: I found this solution worked well. However, LinkedIn seems to only allow media in certain sections, none of which perfectly apply to SO.

Comment: How often does it get refreshed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I honestly don't know. I have last rep change from 7 days ago and it's updated on linkedin.

Comment: @GrzegorzW Thanks, same here, it took between 7 and 10 days for me. Cool trick!

Comment: @SouthShoreAK: what's wrong with the **Summary** section as in Grzegorz's screenshot?

Comment: I've been using this for a while and I think it's a decent way of making your Stack Exchange presence stand out! I also see a refresh inteval of about 7 days in the reputation figure; good enough. Also, if user opens the media block by clicking, up-to-date rep is shown.

Answer (score 16):

Linkedin has a Websites section on your profile.  You can add up to 3 websites so this can be one of them if you find it valuable enough.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to hotlink to an image on a LinkedIn profile?  If so, this might be kind of a duplicate of "[Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image)"

The first answer there includes one user's implementation of image-based flair, since there is no official solution.  But if you're unable to hotlink to an image, then this wouldn't help.

Comment: As far as I could figure out, you cannot do that on LinkedIn.