# How to show my Stack Exchange flair on Linkedin?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair, linkedin

I want to show my Stack Exchange's flair, updating automatically, on Linkedin but i've tried to add a link with no success.
I tryed the methods described in some posts but nothing worked with the new Linkedin's layout.

I've tried the following answers:

[How can I insert my Stack Overflow rating into LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/how-can-i-insert-my-stack-overflow-rating-into-linkedin)

[Why is the Stack Exchange flair showing older image on LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257114/why-is-the-stack-exchange-flair-showing-older-image-on-linkedin)

[Is it possible to show the Stack Exchange flair on LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-the-stack-exchange-flair-on-linkedin)

**That's the result of my attempts:**

[image]

**That's the expected result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that's LinkedIn fault, not SE, i.e. they simply don't support such a thing.

Comment: Also, looks like [this user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244208/how-to-solve-the-issue-of-stretched-stack-overflow-flair-on-the-linkedin-profile) was able to do that, you can try asking him how via a comment or chat.

Comment: I'm not sure this is LinkedIn's fault. They allow embedded content from other sites, and support a wide list of providers through http://embed.ly/ . SE isn't one of them. See https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/34327?lang=en .

Comment: People have been asking for this for years. There was a relatively recent Feature Request to allow us to embed the SE Profiles into LinkedIn at [Add StackExchange profile to LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270245/add-stackexchange-profile-to-linkedin). No movement on that, however.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, it looks like this
[image]

flair gotten from stackexchange general profile, flair tab

[image]