# Why is the Stack Exchange flair showing older image on LinkedIn?

Tags: support, flair, linkedin

**Linkedin Profile**

[image: Linkedin Profile]

**SE Profile**
[image: SE Profile]

I understand that it takes `24 hours - 36 hours` to update but I have been waiting `5 days` for the update. I even tried to delete and add the link/photo again but no luck. Anybody has a solution here? Is it that LinkedIn caches my image or something?

Comment: Your [live flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6177434.png) is fine now, so it's most likely cache in Linkedin site itself, nothing SE can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For users having the same problem, they can clear the cache of LinkedIn by appending a parameter.

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6177434.png
```

to something like this

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6177434.png?theme=default
```

or

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6177434.png?1
```

It cleared the cache of the previous image and the updated flair is being displayed. Remember to create a new parameter every time for the latest flair update.

**EDIT**: It seems like LinkedIn cache system refresh every 7-10 days for the flair to be updated.

Comment: I think that will fix it for now, but it won't actually update very often, right?

Comment: I am not sure, I will have to wait for a day to check. Have you faced the same problem, Patrick?

Comment: With LinkedIn caching, yes. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I guess it takes 7-10 days for the LinkedIn caching system to refresh it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159752/289262

Comment: Actually adding any querystring will have same effect, e.g. http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6177434.png?bustcache=536144

Comment: Yes, I just showed an example :)