# How can I insert my Stack Overflow rating into LinkedIn?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair, linkedin

Is it possible to connect Stack Overflow (or other Stack Exchange) accounts with LinkedIn network? Is it possible to insert your stats into LinkedIn?

Comment: One quick way to do it is to click the "Contact Info" link under your name at the top of the profile page. You can add websites there...but users will have to click the "Contact Info" link to see it.

Answer (score 109):

I've tried to collect all the information about this question. Maybe this helps someone in the future.

- In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-so-flair-on-linkedin) discussion I've found several valuable things:

  1. There is no official way to include your SO flair.
  2. It's not difficult to create this kind of application for LinkedIn.
  3. You can do this using a hack with Google Presentations but to my point of view it looks ugly.
- In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/is-there-any-value-in-creating-an-app-that-will-link-so-and-sf-rep-with-linkedin/23648#23648) discussion people show that SO and LinkedIn companies should make an agreement in order this app to be developed.

So we have a problem of a chicken and an egg. Nobody wants to develop this app before SO and LI have an agreement. And SO and LI do not want to make this agreement because nobody has tried to make this application.

I think we should create a request to LI and SO to develop this feature.

**EDIT:** Recently, I've discovered that it is possible to add links to your LI profile (summary section). Thus, using this feature you may add link to your SO flair into this section and it will display the flair for your SO profile.

Comment: I  have tried "I've discovered that it is possible to add links to your LI profile (summary section)"  it is appearing as attached media like a resume. and cropped pic

Answer (score 93):

I have it in my LinkedIn profile for about 2 years IIRC. Works like a charm. Shows my [combined flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/combined-flair/info) (you can use SO [flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flair/info) if you prefer), displays reputation and number of badges, updates automagically.

Step by step instructions on how to do that are provided eg [here](http://linkedintobusiness.com/--i-212.asp):

> 1. First of all, make sure that you are in edit profile mode.
> 2. Scroll down to your Summary section, your Experience section, or your Education section.
> 3. Click on the add media link that looks like the little square box between the pen and the positioning arrow.
> 4. Add your link. (Your video, image, document or presentation must have a URL address)
> 5. Once you've added the link, you can edit the title field and description.
> 6. Then all you have to do is hit save. And you've got your video your image your presentation smack dab in the middle of your LinkedIn profile.

<kbd>[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/909D0.png]</kbd>

Comment: It may work, IMHO it's quite ugly the way it is being displayed (with that huge border around it and necessary Title under it).

Comment: @LihO what does it mean "can work", it's just works for me for quite a while. As for the title, my understanding is, it's optional. If you believe that it's not needed, simply omit it - see step 5 in instructions quoted "Once you've added the link, you can edit the title field and description."

Comment: No, sorry, I mean... it works. It really does. I just don't like the way it is displayed, but that's the fault of LinkedIn :)

Comment: it says "Sorry, there was a problem processing your request. Please try again." plz help

Comment: I just checked - my flair is shown and up-to-date. Okay, here's what I would do to troubleshoot things: **1)** learn which side to blame - try uploading some other, non-flair image (from both local computer and from Internet). If it loads, it means LinkedIn side is okay **2)** check if i set correct URL for a flair - in your case it should be `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1997103.png` **3)** check if I can load this image to my local computer instead of LinkedIn and view it there

Comment: thanx a lot it works @gnat

Comment: To remove the border you can `add ?theme=clean` or `?theme=dark` or `?theme=hotdog` to the end of the image URL e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1997103.png?theme=clean`

Comment: But the image is not getting updated as in SE flair page. What is the solution?

Comment: Thanks although linkedIn has changed its interface. It was pretty much smooth.

Comment: If you try to edit the Summary and don't see the add link button, it's probably because your summary is empty. So write "Summary", for example, hit save, and then try to edit again. The options to add media should appear.

Comment: Not sure this works anymore. Currently you are offered a single text field asking for a url with a link to 'supported providers'

Comment: Worth noting that these 'links' don't show to the public, only to 'connections'.

Comment: Adding the link in Linkedin does show the flair, but it's all stretched and distorted. Any way we can resize or make it display properly?

Comment: ugh.. seems that linkedin caches the image link. I just checked my link (which I placed some time ago thanks to this answer :) and I found it has not updated the rep I gained since... posting the link again gives the same result; I eventually added a *different* link (added the clean theme) and it updated.

Comment: @DarkCygnus You can force LinkedIn to use the latest, uncached flair by appending `?latest` to the flair link.

Comment: Does it work by adding the badge as a media link? Because it looks kinda ugly in the preview on LinkedIn's edit-profile screen.

Comment: Does this still work? The flair is cropped when I insert it as a media link and needs to be clicked to be readable

Answer (score 43):

After tinkering with this for some time, I have come to the conclusion that for me, the best approach is to link to my SO profile from within the Accomplishments -> Certifications section.  It requires some manual maintenance (i.e. adjusting your profile score or whatever else you want to list) but it looks better than embedding the flair image.  Here is how to do it:

1. In the Accomplishments section, click the plus (+), then click Certification:

[image: Add Certification 1]

2. Complete the form, making sure to select "Stack Overflow" as the Certification Authority.  You can specify anything that you would like for the name.  As you can see here, I am listing Skeet's score.

[image: Add Certification 2]

3. Here is how the finished product looks.  Notice there is an appropriately sized SO logo and a link to Skeet's profile.

[image: Add Certification 3]

Depending on what you enter for the Certification Name, you may have to periodically update your profile to reflect your current reputation or whatever else have listed (top x percentage, # of badges, etc).

Answer (score 22):

Yeah, if LinkedIn profile allows to show images, yes.

Use Flair, more about Flairs here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Here's mine

[image: profile for Martin at Meta Stack Overflow, Q&A for the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites]

or combined/summarized

[image: profile for Martin on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: I know about this feature. Moreover, you can create profile in StackExchange Careers and put it link. But I want to find standard way how to do this. In LinkedIn I have not found any place where I can put this information. Maybe there is an application or smthg similar that is available for stackexchange.

Comment: martin problem is specific site fair like stackover flow looks urgy as it is not properly display as an thumbnail on profile. only combine show the perfect on linkden

Comment: In this way, the bad thing is that as your reputation grows your presentation won’t show your updated flair. You’ll have to open the presentation and re-add the flair image to reflect your current SO reputation.

Answer (score 19):

Other answers are valid, but not so straightforward, IMHO. So here is a very simple solution, as of 2020.

1. Use the following link: `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2778822.png?theme=dark&latest` *(using `latest` keeps it up to date)*
2. Replace `2778822` by your SO ID, found on your profile https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair
3. (optional) Change the `theme` parameter (accepted values are listed on the previous link)
4. Use this link in your LinkedIn "About" section. Click `Add profile section -> Recommended -> Featured -> Link`. And paste the link of stackoverflow flair.

> I personally used `StackOverflow - Top 3% #socratic #necromancer` as link's "Title", but you can use anything you like

---

Example with my LinkedIn profile:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ambroise-dhenain/

[image]

---

> Here is what the "edit media" view looks like, as of 2020:

[image]

Comment: To add it, go to profile -> add profile section -> Link. and paste the link of stackoverflow flair.

Comment: Thanks @LouisGo, I've added this to the answer.

Comment: 2nd step incorrect - that number is **not** your stackoverflow userID (which is longer) and will not work with SO id

Comment: @LouisGo - there is `link` in `profile -> add profile section -> ...` - I only see an accordion of `core`, `recommended`, `additional` and no `link` item under any of them

Comment: @vsync, the sections in my previous comment was referring to linkedin profile, not SO profile. You may see this post's #4

Comment: Obviously Linkedin profile and not SO profile... I think you can only add what has not been already-added, so this is why I don't see `Featured`

Comment: I haven't checked thoroughly, but I recently noticed this is broken indeed, I believe this answer was valid until SO removed support for "Job profile", which in turn removed that feature. As my own SO integration within my LinkedIn profile was broken a few weeks ago. For reference, SO decided not to be used as a tool for recruiting/resume a few months back.

Comment: @vsync Sorry, it's now `linkedin -> profile->add profile section -> recommended -> add Featured` but I'm not sure if flair is still working.

Comment: Yes, on LinkedIn. But the SO "flair" doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend following the approach suggested in the [answer by Vadorequest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343702/203593) but using [se-flair](https://se-flair.appspot.com/) instead of the flair provided by stackexchange.

The reason for this recommendation is simply because se-flair allows you to change the size of the png and thus avoid the crappy resolution that ends up showing on your profile if you use the png from https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/.png

So:

1. In you linkedin profile select `Add profile section` > `Featured` > `Links`.
2. Paste the link to your se-falir:

   `https://se-flair.appspot.com/<userid>@5x.png`

   - where `<userid>` is your SE user id. To find it simply have a look at the url of your profile on stackexchange, it will look something like: *`https://stackexchange.com/users/1779931/jojo`*. You guessed right, the number after `users/` is your user id.
   - do not forget to put the **@5x** directly after your userid! This is the resolution multiplier that is responsible for the better resolution (here 5 times the original resolution).
     So the link might look like this: *`https://se-flair.appspot.com/1779931@5x.png`*
3. Add *Title* and *Description* to your Featured link, and you are done.

You'll end up with a high-res (but still cropped) flair under the `Featured` selection in your profile (e.g. https://www.linkedin.com/in/j-i-l/).

Comment: This is great but somehow in the generated link, I'm getting more reputation than what I actually have.

Comment: @NicoE what is reported is actually the total amount of points over all SE sites you have an account. It is not just the reputation of StackOverflow. But in a way this also better reflects all your contributions, which is not a bad thing if you ask me.

Comment: Doesn't work, invalid link.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't stackoverflow (SO) and LinkedIn have competing business models? 
>   I believe stackoverflow and LinkedIn would never allow integration with each others network.

Both have strong social networking elements. SO's reputation is a far superior metric for endorsing ones knowledge as it comes from other techies reviewing your answers with much more insight and technical depth, whereas LinkedIn's endorsements are kind of shallow.

Recruiters have recently started using SO to search for candidates and contact them. I have been contacted a couple of times from SO.

It's important to keep in mind that the primary goal of SO is to build a community of fellow programmers, where they can help each other... however the propensity of good programmers (who want-to/can help others) with being a great hire is very high... hence the newly evolve use of SO for finding and hiring great programming talent is happening. And why not, it does make sense.

Comment: Why the down votes? would you like to explain if you disagree. If you have successfully posted your live stackoverflow profile on LinkedIn?

Comment: I think you're right but also wrong at the same time. The primary purpose of SO has always been to help fellow programmers. Expanding to "jobs" is just a side effect. Whereas LinkedIn has always been a professional social network. Yes you're right that SO looks as a competition, but really isn't. You could say the same thing about GitHub.

Comment: SO Reputation is a measure of your ability to regurgitate simple answers to simple problems.