# Add StackExchange profile to LinkedIn?

Tags: feature-request, linkedin

I am an active member of the SharePoint StackExchange forum/community. I would like to add a link and description of my experience as a member of StackExchange on my **LinkedIn profile**. I am confused as to under which **section** should I add these details?

Also, it would be really nice if StackExchange comes up with something similar to what **Codeschool** has implemented... **Add to my LinkedIn Profile** facility. All we need to do is to click on that link and the course that we completed is added to our LinkedIn Profile.

**Edit 1:** Codeschool is just a website for online tutorials, offering range of technical courses (Free as well as paid). Check this [link](https://www.codeschool.com/)

After completion of courses they offer certificates and at the end of the course on the Certifiacte/Badge page they provide a link to add that certificate to our LinkedIn Profile. Find the snap below: 
[image]

Upon clicking this link the course is added under the **Certification section** of **LinkedIn** without us having to take any further trouble.

Comment: Well, what you have is your [global flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6843349.png) that can be embedded as image anywhere.

Comment: [How can I insert my Stack Overflow rating into LinkedIn?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121355/165773)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But this won't remain updated automatically with the growing reputation on this Community, right? I mean, I will have to keep on adding  Global Flair whenever there is a change in reputation

Comment: Depends on LinkedIn. If they let you have the actual image (and not copying static version to their servers) then it's updated once every 24 hours. To know this, try adding it, then in your actual profile, view the source of the image.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for this useful information

Comment: @gnat Thanks for a useful link

Comment: Anyway, found a dupe, turns out this was asked before. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This wasn't a duplicate as I have asked for feature request too (see second para)

Comment: I don't know what is "Codeschool", and so most others, so first explain what you mean exactly, with details about what you ask Stack Exchange to do, then I can reopen it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Check updated question

Comment: Cheers, reopened and added relevant tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a nice suggestion. Someone could create an app to do this, Stack Exchange, or even you yourself if you are a little familiar with programming on the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) (or want to learn).

Another option is to embed your SE profile as 'content' (through the Link option in LinkedIn). Currently LinkedIn doesn't support embedding your profile nicely. I have tried it with one of my questions, and it doesn't render that nice. It just shows a blown up SE icon, although it understands the question format.

I am not sure who would need to make a change to make this work beautifully. [LinkedIn uses Embed.ly](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34327/), possibly SE needs to do something to support the data format they request.

Comment: I am not too familiar with programming on API, but I will definitely give this a try

Comment: @YashSaraiya Any luck?

Comment: Not yet. Actually, I haven't tried this from quite a time :-(