# Add Flair to LinkedIn Profile Summary via Embedly?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, flair, linkedin

Related questions have been asked several times over the years, but there was just a LinkedIn interface upgrade today (Feb 28, 2017) and I wonder if we are one step closer to creating a solution...

Acknowledged related questions: (please don't flag question, as I am adding the Embedly part to my question.)

- [How can I insert my Stack Overflow rating into LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/how-can-i-insert-my-stack-overflow-rating-into-linkedin)
- [Is it possible to show the Stack Exchange flair on LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-the-stack-exchange-flair-on-linkedin)
- [Add StackExchange profile to LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270245/add-stackexchange-profile-to-linkedin)
- [How to show my Stack Exchange flair on Linkedin?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287095/how-to-show-my-stack-exchange-flair-on-linkedin)
- [Add badge to LinkedIn profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309151/add-badge-to-linkedin-profile)

---

So with the latest UI, you will see:

[image: profile edit icon]

Which will allow you to edit your profile.  At the bottom of the displayed modal window you will see a Summary box:

[image: profile summary text area]

Pasting the Stack Exchange flair code directly into the box doesn't work — it won't render the HTML.  (This is nothing new.)  If you click the "Supported Formats" link, you will see a short explanation which includes a link to a [full list of rich media content](https://embed.ly/embed/features/providers) to embed.ly

Alas, there is no Stack Exchange on the list!

The question part: This is the way forward, right?  Have Stack Exchange and LinkedIn gone far enough to enable this feature to actually happen?  Is the final step that Stack Exchange, LinkedIn, and Embedly just need to make things official so we can all flair up our LinkedIn profiles?  Gosh, I hope so, because LinkedIn endorsements have absolutely no credibility, and Stack Exchange flair gives an untold audience a verifiable metric and a lead to investigate the actual expertise and professionalism of a person willing to volunteer their Stack Exchange username.

Comment: I suppose, to show a volume of interest that LI can appreciate, we should upvote this post in their help forum: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/466651

Answer (score 6):

The flair is just an image so you can put the image URL in via the "Link to media" button.

> [image]

It does show a not-so-good cropped version until you click through though, which isn't ideal.

> [image]

Stack Exchange becoming a supported Embedly provider specifically for the flair is unlikely; at least with the flair's current form. [Become an Embedly Provider](http://embed.ly/providers/new) says (I picked a few relevant points—there are more):

> we ask that you make sure your Embed meets the following requirements.
>
> - The embed needs to be novel, in that it provides some functionality to the end user. i.e play a video, scroll through a Behance portfolio or view a slideshow.
> - The embed must be responsive and, at minimum, work between 280 and 800 pixels.
> - Your site needs to support oEmbed or Twitter Player Cards as way for Embedly to reliable match a URL to a piece of content.

The flair is not novel; it is a single static image and not really responsive.

The few current Embedly providers that do link to singular images do so in a responsive manner and add extra interactivity. So using Embedly for the flair is probably a non-starter for now.

Comment: Adding the link to flair image in Linkedin show the image all stretched and distorted. Is there any way to make the image display properly?